# How do I get all images from a folder in the Firebase Storage and displayed them in a listview

Tags: android, listview, firebase, android-recyclerview, firebase-storage

So I'm learning about Firebase Storage for android and I've hit a wall. I want to get all the images I have stored in a folder in my Firebase Storage and once I get a reference to them I want to stored them in a ListView or RecyclerView. How Do i do that? I mean I can get reference to the folder:

```
StorageReference storageReference =  FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("gallery");
```

But then how do I get all the images in the gallery folder and display them in a Listview or recyclerView?

Answer (score 1):

There currently is no API call in Firebase Storage to list all files in a folder. If you need such functionality, you should store the metadata of the files (such as the download URLs) in a place where you can list them. The [Firebase Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write) is perfect for this and allows you to also easily share the URLs with others.

add image name to the [Firebase Realtime Databse](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write) and fetch from it

and get Url like ,

```
mStoreRef.child("<folderNameInStorage>/" +""<imageName>).getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener();
```

this is the way.

Comment: Yea I suspected as much. That's a very clever solution. Thank you so much!!

Comment: I just implemented the exact same solution. It is annoying that still there isn't any ref.listAll() function.